# undefined reference to function that looks ok

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linked-list, undefined

I have the following code:

```
void delete_linkedlist(LinkedList* ll,void (*destroy_data)(void*)){

    if(!ll->next){//check if next exists 
            delete_linkedlist(ll->next,destroy_data);//recursive call 
            if(destroy_data){ //if we can destroy the data  
            destroy_data(ll->data); //destroy data 
                free(ll); 
        }
    }else{ 
         free(ll); //else just free the linked list 
    }
}
void delete_hashmap(HashMap* hm,void (*destroy_data)(void*)){
    for(int i=0;i<hm->key_space;i++){//loop over every set of linked lists 
        LinkedList* loc = hm->datapointers[i];
        if(loc) //if not null 
            delete_linkedList(loc,destroy_data);//delete linked list <<<this goes wrong?
        }
}
```

this returns the following error with make: `undefined reference to`delete_linkedList'` 
but to me it looks it shouldn't be a problem as delete_linked_list is defined directly above the function where it is used. And is called with the same parameters as it's defined above, anybody know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete_linkedList
```

Check your case `delete_linkedlist()`

Answer (score 1):

C and Linux are case-sensitive. `delete_linkedlist()` and `delete_linkedList()` are not the same in C and Linux. You are defining the function as `delete_linkedlist()` and calling as `delete_linkedList()`, hence the error. You should have searched for the exact string reported in the error using a good editor before posting your question.

Comment: While you're right that the issue is case sensitivity, it has nothing to do with linux. C is a case sensitive language.

Comment: @nos Ofcourse, the C language, the gcc compiler and Linux operating system, all are case sensitive.